# IOS - App slicing : Will app slicing work with only 2x images

Tags: ios

If app slicing is enabled and only 2x images are added to assets library. Will 3x,1x devices download 2x images acordingly ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this configuration should work.

You can simulate this by exporting your app using Xcode.

- Select "Generic iOS Device" or a real iOS Device
- Product > Archive
- In the Organizer, select the latest archive for your app
- Export
- Save for Development Deployment
- Choose your signing identity
- Export for specific devices > Choose a device you want to test (for example iPhone 7 Plus)
- Install the app on your device and check the assets
- Alternatively, unzip the resulting IPA and inspect the asset catalog with a tool like [AssetCatalogTinkerer](https://github.com/insidegui/AssetCatalogTinkerer)